# Win10: How to display art on second display with lock screen activated?

Tags: windows-10

My displays are always on, and I like to have artwork on them.

But when the screen is locked, only the primary display shows anything.

How do I:

a) Get the OS to push an image to second and/or third displays when the console is locked?

b) Control which image (or mp4) is looped to that display?

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 10, Microsoft has disabled multi-monitor lock screens.
So you need third-party software for that.
Under Windows, the lock-screen will display on the main monitor,
while the others will be blank.

Try for example
[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/),
although the Pro version might be needed.

Other possibilities are
[Dual Monitor Tools](http://dualmonitortool.sourceforge.net/),
[UltraMon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)
or
[Stardock](https://www.stardock.com/products/).

Comment: Thanks! DisplayFusion appears to be the most advanced of those tools, and the only tool with clear support for wallpaper (and possibly lock screen, that aspect is not completely clear from the docs I found). Will pursue.

Comment: Well, the folks at DisplayFusion say their tool lacks this ability.  So it appears there is no way to do it at this time. (I did not look deeply at the other tools, as this is an advanced feature, and DisplayFusion seems to be the most actively developed of these tools).

Comment: If it's important to you, try the other tools, in case one works. If none works, this is a sign that Microsoft truly disabled all the possibilities.

Comment: I have been in touch with the folks at DisplayFusion. They are aware of the need for the feature, and seem to have it on their radar. I can't speak to the technical feasibility. That is not my direct problem.